# Content reset and autohide element after some seconds in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a DIV like this:

```
<div id="message">This is my message</div>
```

Message populating by `ajax`

```
$('#message').append(json.message);
$('#message').show();
```

Now I need to hide this `DIV` after 5 seconds. When this hide I need to remove all the contents of this `#message` DIV.

My problem is I can hide this div, but I can't reset `div` contents.

This is the way I use to hide my div

```
$('#message').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
```

Hope somebody may help me out. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a callback to the jQuery fadeOut function, that will run when the animation is complete. In this case, we are setting the html to be empty.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#message').fadeOut('slow', function(){
         $(this).html(""); 
    });
}, 5000);
```

EDIT:

Or if you'd prefer to use the delay function like you currently have:

```
$('#message').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $(this).html(""); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code:

```
$('#message').html("This is my message");
```

**UPDATE**

```
var message = $('#message');
message.append(" .. some JSON data added");
message.show();
var intv = setInterval(showing, 5000);
function showing(){
    message.fadeOut('slow');
    clearInterval(intv);
    message.html("This is my message");
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t0nrkg0s/)

Comment: No I need to remove the contents when the element `fadeout`